# Adding a value to x axis labeling in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis-labels

I want the x axis of my chart to be labelled with the date and the build number.
How can I achieve this?

Here is a fiddle of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/up9eetkg/

The data is structured like this:

```
var data = arrData.map(function(d) {
    return {
        date: parseDate(d[0]),
        buildNb: d[1],
        failure: d[2],
        all: d[3]
    };
});
```

Comment: Your best bet for something like this is to create the labels manually instead of relying on the axis component.

Comment: and how can this be done? I only used the axis component so far.

Comment: You want to plot two distinct things on the same axis: the build number and the dates. This is impossible since your domain contains the same date value e.g. `2014-10-28`, with difference in the build number. Should these points be plotted over each other? The other solution is to give up on an temporal axis and just use an ordinal axis: http://jsfiddle.net/mv15fmzy/1/ Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: E.g. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/up9eetkg/1/